# More than one 'select' statement in a query

Tags: php, sql

Having some difficulties with PHP returning results behavior, it seems if there is more than one select statement within the SQL statement no results return. (However works fine when executing in management studio)

If I comment the parts of the query that give me extended information (the first two selects into temporary tables) and the join on the last select then the query works fine so I've narrowed it down to being an issue with multiple selects.

So this code with mentioned sections commented out works fine.

```
foreach ($_POST['BeginLocation'] as $key => $value) {$LocationID = $key;}

echo '<div class="nmform"><form name="StockTake" action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';

include "../DBCon/RDPNearMisses.php";

$GetProducts = sqlsrv_query($NMDB, "/*select ProductID, max(StockTakeDate) as 'NewestStk'
                                    into #temp1
                                    from [JobObservations].[dbo].[ITStk.StockTake]
                                    where StockTakeDate > DATEADD(d, -14, GETDATE())
                                    group by ProductID

                                    select ST.ProductID, ST.StockTakeDate, ST.Qty
                                    into #temp2
                                    from [JobObservations].[dbo].[ITStk.StockTake] ST
                                    inner join #temp1 t1 on ST.ProductID = T1.ProductID and ST.StockTakeDate = T1.NewestStk

                                    --drop table #temp1*/

                                    select PG.GroupName, PD.ProductID, PD.ProductGroupID, PD.ProductCode, PD.ProductDescription--, t2.Qty as [LastQty]
                                    from [JobObservations].[dbo].[ITStk.Products] as PD
                                    inner join [JobObservations].[dbo].[ITStk.ProductGroups] as PG on PD.ProductGroupID = PG.ProductGroupID
                                    inner join [JobObservations].[dbo].[ITStk.Locations] as LC on PD.LocationID = LC.LocationID
                                    --left join #temp2 t2 on PD.ProductID = t2.ProductID
                                    where PD.LocationID = $LocationID
                                    order by LC.LocationDescription asc, PG.GroupName asc, PD.ProductCode asc

                                    --drop table #temp2");

if( $GetProducts === false ) {
    if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null) {
        foreach( $errors as $error ) {
            echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']."<br />";
            echo "code: ".$error[ 'code']."<br />";
            echo "message: ".$error[ 'message']."<br />";
        }
    }
}
echo '<table class="questiontable" style="width: 600px;"><th style=width: 50%;>Code</th><th>Description</th><th style="width: 50px;">Qty</th><th>LastQty</th>';
while ($row1= sqlsrv_fetch_array($GetProducts))
{
         if ($ProductGroupCheck != $row1['ProductGroupID']) {echo '<tr><td style="font-weight: bold; font-size: larger;" colspan="3";>'.$row1['GroupName'].'</td></tr>';}
         echo '<tr class="rowb"><td>'.$row1['ProductCode'].'</td><td>'.$row1['ProductDescription'].'</td><td><select class="styled-select" name="StockArray['.$row1['ProductID'].']" required><option selected></option><option>0</option><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option><option>6</option><option>7</option><option>8</option><option>9</option><option>10</option><option>11</option><option>12</option><option>13</option><option>14</option><option>15</option></select></td><td>'.$row1['LastQty'].'</td></tr>';
         $ProductGroupCheck = $row1['ProductGroupID'];
}
echo '</table>';
```

if the SQL is ammended to below the query returns no results (and no SQL error is thrown from the check)

```
"select ProductID, max(StockTakeDate) as 'NewestStk'
                                    into #temp1
                                    from [JobObservations].[dbo].[ITStk.StockTake]
                                    where StockTakeDate > DATEADD(d, -14, GETDATE())
                                    group by ProductID

                                    select ST.ProductID, ST.StockTakeDate, ST.Qty
                                    into #temp2
                                    from [JobObservations].[dbo].[ITStk.StockTake] ST
                                    inner join #temp1 t1 on ST.ProductID = T1.ProductID and ST.StockTakeDate = T1.NewestStk

                                    drop table #temp1

                                    select PG.GroupName, PD.ProductID, PD.ProductGroupID, PD.ProductCode, PD.ProductDescription, t2.Qty as [LastQty]
                                    from [JobObservations].[dbo].[ITStk.Products] as PD
                                    inner join [JobObservations].[dbo].[ITStk.ProductGroups] as PG on PD.ProductGroupID = PG.ProductGroupID
                                    inner join [JobObservations].[dbo].[ITStk.Locations] as LC on PD.LocationID = LC.LocationID
                                    left join #temp2 t2 on PD.ProductID = t2.ProductID
                                    where PD.LocationID = $LocationID
                                    order by LC.LocationDescription asc, PG.GroupName asc, PD.ProductCode asc

                                    drop table #temp2");
```

I also tried changing this to a stored procedure and executing it in the PHP and the behavior is the same.

Please ignore the fact I have variables inside the code, I will write this as a prepared statement when I get it working.

Comment: The doc says: "sqlsrv_query — Prepares and executes a query". A query, not queries.

Comment: You could try to use union all, but you have to make sure that all queries return the same number of columns

Comment: Also, the last statement in your combined sql is a "drop table". What would you expect it to return?

Comment: Sergio - I would expect it to return the same as sql management studio or executing a stored procedure from within crystal reports - the results - but i'm no expert so you tell me how php/sql_srv driver will behave?

George, can't make union all work in this case as the first two selects get info for a column on the last select.

Comment: @Dave: drop table doesn't return any results. Certainly not a recordset. Because it's not a select statement.

Comment: Sergio, as a test I tried commenting out the last drop table so a select is the last statement in the batch and it hasn't made a difference. But even if it was that you can't drop the table before the last select or it wont be able to join the results set.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: why do you drop temp tables? they'll be gone anyway when you close that connection

Comment: and i'd put `set nocount on `in the first line maybe its getting confused by the `(xx) rows inserted `messages generated by the first 2 statements

Comment: @Aツ I just asked myself that question and the answer is I don't need to.. I just have that there for when i'm developing the query so I can run it more than once as I change things. I've removed both drop tables however the same issue stands.

Comment: @Aツ You legend, no count on did the trick

If you want to submit that as an answer ill accept it if you care about that?

Comment: @Dave: huh, I'm honestly surprised this worked :) at least mysql libs do raise an exception, I think.

Comment: @Sergio No problem, unfortunately i've only used MS SQL Server so I couldn't say one way or the other.. I did think sqlsrv_query could handle a batch but I didn't want to be rude as I'm not an expert :)

Comment: @Dave: Neither am I. But all signs pointed to this being not possible. Until Aツ showed up :)